# Problema con etiqueta track html5 y subtítulos en video

Tags: html5, video

estoy intentando usar la etiqueta  en Html5 de la siguiente manera:

```
<video id="videplayer" width="350" controls>
    <source src="./videoplayback.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track src="./sub1.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="es" label="Español">
</video>
```

El fichero de subtítulos tiene la siguiente forma:

```
WEBVTT

1
00:01.000 --> 00:04.000

Hola. ¿Qué tal?
```

Y no veo subtítulos por ningún sitio. He probado en Firefox y Chrome y con distintos videos .mp4, pero no consigo que aparezcan, y eso que parece algo sencillo.
Los ficheros están en sus rutas correctas.

¿Alguna idea o algún caso parecido?

Comment: Hola bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a que leas la sección [¿Cómo creo un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sigas los consejos y aumentes tus posibilidades de recibir una respuesta a tu problema. Para mas información puedes visitar la página de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: te fijaste en el sub menú del reproductor? se encuentra al presionar los 3 puntos.

Comment: Si, lo tenía claro, además en la etiqueta track al poner label="Español" aparece como opción al elegir si activar o no los subtitulos.

Comment: Al final, la clave del problema era que al ejecutar el html en local, sin un servidor local, como XAMPP por ejemplo, el navegador al usar el protocolo file:/// limita ciertas características, como por ejemplo esta de plasmar los subtítulos en un video.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que hay carácter incorrecto ó fuera de lugar en tu archivo `.vtt` como el número 1 solitario ahí.

La estructura de éste archivo `.vtt` es delicado. Se debe ubicar bien el tiempo de inicio y finalización de cada sección de texto a mostrar.

El formato es: **hh:mm:ss.mmm** (pero en tu caso es: **mm:ss:mmm**) de la siguiente manera:

```
WEBVTT

00:01.000 --> 00:04.000
Hola. ¿Qué tal?

00:05.000 --> 00:08.000
Muy bien!
```

Comment: He descubierto que subiendo los ficheros a un servidor web funciona sin problemas, pero ejecutándolo en local, el mismo fichero, no hay manera.
El formato de fichero que pasa @NarcisoAifuz, como digo, funciona en el servidor web, pero en local no (al menos en mi caso).

No he encontrado en ningún sitio oficial que diga que es necesario un servidor web...así que me sigue quedando la duda si es posible que funcione en local.

Comment: Éste yo probé localmente, y me funcionó muy bien. Debe haber otro problema: tu navegador, tu editor, o la ruta del archivo, o algo

Comment: El único navegador con el que funciona es IE y no en todos, si no que he probado en distintos PCs.
Con el resto nada...¿podrías decirme con que navegador has probado?, porque está claro que no es cosa del editor ni de la ruta.

Comment: Entonces hay un error en alguna parte que tenes que encontrar. El código en sí funciona muy bien, Está bien estructurado